Endless indexing of point clouds in QGIS
I am creating a QGIS plugin that processes point clouds. When creating a QgsPointCloudLayer object in QGIS, indexing of this layer begins. But this indexing reaches 100% and is not completed.
I was trying to specify the path to the files .las, .laz, .copc.laz, but the result was always the same - endless indexing. If you add this cloud point to QGIS manually (by dragging or layer - > add layer), then everything will work fine.
I tried to create a QgsPointCloudLayer in the Python console (which is inside QGIS) and it worked. But it doesn't work inside the plugin.
    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
       input = self.parameterAsPointCloudLayer(parameters, self.INPUT, context).source()
       output = self.parameterAsFileOutput(parameters, self.OUTPUT, context)

       #processing point cloud
       #...

       # adding layer
       layer = QgsPointCloudLayer(output, "New layer", 'pdal')

       if not layer.isValid():
           feedback.pushInfo("invalid layer!")
       else:
           feedback.pushInfo("layer loaded!")
           QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)

       return {self.name(): 0}



Have a look at the Flags & Best practice sections here: https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html#flags including the highlighted tip. Loading layers to the project inside the processAlgorithm() method is not thread-safe. Either override the flags() method and return QgsProcessingAlgorithm.FlagNoThreading or, even better, use a QgsProcessingParameterPointCloudDestination.

I get the error “.las” files are not supported as outputs for this qgis algorithm when using QgsProcessingParameterPointCloudDestination
